# Unable to understand how lambda layer work in keras?

Tags: lambda, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to understand the Siamese network given as a [example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_siamese_graph.py) in the keras repository.

The networks add a lambda as output to the model , by the following line

```
model = Model(input=[input_a, input_b], output=distance)
```

where distance is defined as lambda as

```
distance = Lambda(euclidean_distance, output_shape=eucl_dist_output_shape)([processed_a, processed_b])
```

The other two function defined as:

```
def euclidean_distance(vects):
    x, y = vects
    return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True))


def eucl_dist_output_shape(shapes):
    shape1, shape2 = shapes
    return (shape1[0], 1)
```

Now I am not able to understand what does this lambda layer pass on to the next layer.

Keras defines lambda as

```
Lambda(function,output_shape,arguments)
```

So i guess the input coming from previous layer is processed by function and returned as the output in the desired shape.
Now according to me the function euclidean distance when applied would return a row vector representing the distance of each pair in the current batch. So the dimension of such a result would be something like

```
batch_size * 1
```

Now the function `eucl_dist_output_shape` would transform its shape , what i am not able to understand is what exactly is this function doing here and what it is calculating,what is `return (shape1[0],1)` achieving in this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input for this lambda layer is `[processed_a, processed_b]`.

The function that it runs is `euclidean_distance`, and what it passes forward is `K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True))`. Being `x`, and `y` taken from the input.

This is the only real processing going on. This is the one that rules the shape either.

The inputs seem to be of shape `(batch, n)`, and the outputs will be `(batch,1)`. The `n` will disappear because of the `sum` function with `axis=1`. But since it uses `keepdims=True`, the axis will be preserved as 1.

Now, the output shape is not really doing anything. It's not necessary to have this function if you're using Tensorflow. But if you're using Theano, you need it because Theano cannot understand the shapes from the calculations.

This function is just returning the shape `(batch,1)`, because the creator of the function know that this is the output shape.

The input of this output shape function is `[shapeOfProcessed_a, shapeOfProcessed_b]`. They're just taking the batch size from one of the input shapes.